# Android Studio - Scrolling page with multiple textviews

Tags: java, android, scroll, rss

To help with the explanation of what I'm trying to do I'll use the example of twitter (RSS feed concept).

A single activity with multiple bodies of text that all move simultaneously on the page.

I understand how to use a scroll view, however this only allows for one scrolling body of text. What I'm seeking is all textviews to scroll collectively as I move up or down the page.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Have you ever heard of a `ListView`?

Comment: @EricB. I have not, I'm really new to android studio. I'll youtube it now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour what you described is exactly the function of a `ListView` . If you never used it before, take a look at this tutorial for example: http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

Comment: Will check it out now! Are ListView's scrollable? Thank you Gex

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, ListViews are absolutely scrollable :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html